# Update SD card when adding audio files

Tags: kotlin, sd-card, mediastore

I am inserting audio files onto the SD card using the Android Studio Device Explorer. In order to inform MediaStore of the insertion I have to cool boot the emulator or, when using the phone, restart it . Is there a way to do this programmatically?